# select option des not work in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to display the value have chosen, but it does not seem to be working. Any ideas?

Here is the code:

```
    <label>Apply to <%= statement_display_name.downcase %>:</label> <%= 
    f.select( :statement_id, 
    options_for_select(@client.statements.unpaid.collect { |statement| 
    [statement_display_name + " #{statement.number_with_prefix} #
    {statement.created_or_bill_date.to_date} - #
    {number_to_currency(statement.outstanding_amount)}"]}), :selected 
     => f.object.statement_id )%>
```

Comment: Can you elaborate upon "does not seem to be working"?

Comment: is not choosing the option automatically with the statement id, gets back to default value instead, which is the first one.

Answer (score 0):

You're passing an array as the options, but you'll need a hash of `your_string => statement_id` instead to make this work.

Right now the options don't make reference to the statement ID as their value. You pass it an array of `[[some_string], [some_string]]`, whereas you probably need `{some_string => statement_id, some_other_string => statement_id}`

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it was helpful to figure out the issue.

This sorted it  out : 

         <label>Apply to <%= statement_display_name.downcase %>:</label> 
         <%= select_tag :statement_id, 
         options_for_select(@client.statements.unpaid.collect { |statement| 
         [statement_display_name + " #{statement.number_with_prefix} #
         {statement.created_or_bill_date.to_date} - #
         {number_to_currency(statement.outstanding_amount)}"]}, 
         params[:statement_id]),prompt: "-----"%>

Comment: Cool! You should reply to your question with that, and mark it as the answer :)